# why "gtest" in ros giving CMake Error when i compile the code?

Tags: ros, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am running a simple gtest, when i compile my package with catkin_make,  i am getting below error. Can anyone help to resolve this?

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:71 (message):
  catkin_add_executable_with_gtest() must be called after catkin_package() so
  that default output directories for the executables are defined
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:34 (catkin_add_executable_with_gtest)
  ros_gtest/CMakeLists.txt:26 (catkin_add_gtest)
```

i followed this link  http://ysonggit.github.io/coding/2014/12/19/use-gtest-in-ros-program.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234075/why-%22gtest%22-in-ros-giving-cmake-error-when-i-compile-the-code?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error explains itself reasonably well:

> catkin_add_executable_with_gtest() must be called after catkin_package()

In your CMakeLists.txt, you need to call catkin_package() before you call catkin_add_executable_with_gtest().

It looks like the tutorial you're following is missing this step (but it's included in the author's sample repository)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-05-10**:
Thank you so much, your answer was helped me to resolve the issue.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-12**:
@anilmullapudi: please accept the answer by @ahendrix by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.